# Looking for regexp or string function

Tags: sql, regex, string, vertica

I have a URL that I'm parsing which is below:

```
/visitor/browseJobDetails.do?comeFrom=email&jobId=3931052&distance=18&rx=email_NJNY%7CProvider_Featured%7Cjobtitle%7C91942%7CCHILDCARE`
```

I'm looking to be able to grab the integers between "email&jobId=" and "&distance".  So in this case 3931052.  Could anyone help me using either regexp or vertica string fucntions (substring, instring, etc...)

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking?

Comment: Handling URLs is not a new problem.  What is your source language?  I will bet you a nickel there is existing code that has been written, tested and debugged that handles URLs for you.  In PHP, you want to use `parse_url()`.

Comment: I've tried using instring and substring, but for some reason, I cannot wrap my head around how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure I know the answer to that question

Comment: @AndyLester This is in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex will work, but it is much simpler to use a function that is included in your language (for example, PHP's `parse_url()`, or Ruby's `URI.parse()`).

Anyways, for a regex that you could use, here's an example:

```
^.*\?comeFrom\=([^&]+)&jobId\=([0-9]+)&distance\=([0-9]+).*$
```

and then replace it with `$2`, or `\2` (depending on your language).

Here's what the regex does:

`^` matches the beginning of the string
`.*` matches any character, any amount of times
`\?comeFrom\=` matches literally **?comeFrom=** 
`([^&]+)` matches any character that is not **&** one or more times. It is also the first capture group
`&jobId\=` matches literally **&jobId=**
`([0-9]+)` matches any number one or more times. It is also the second capture group
`&distance\=` matches literally **&distance=**
`([0-9]+)` matches any number one or more times. It is also the third capture group.
`.*` matches any character, any amount of times
`$` matches the end of the string

[Here's an example of the regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/gJ9cS2/1) on regex101.com

When replacing the string with `$2` or `\2`, you are replacing it with the second capture group, which in this case will be the  `jobId` parameter.

Comment: Curious, why do you escape `=`?

Comment: @zerkms I may be wrong, but I think that in some languages it is a reserved character in regexes

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version with lookahead/lookbehind patterns. It will match a number - `(\d+)` that between `email&jobId=` and `&distance` only.

```
regexp_substr(:URL, '.*(?<=email&jobId\=)(\d+)(?=&distance).*', 1, 1, 'c', 1);
```

---

```
daniel=> select regexp_substr($$/visitor/browseJobDetails.do?comeFrom=email&jobId=3931052&distance=18&rx=email_NJNY%7CProvider_Featured%7Cjobtitle%7C91942%7CCHILDCARE`$$, '.*(?<=email&jobId\=)(\d+)(?=&distance).*', 1, 1, 'c', 1);
 regexp_substr
---------------
 3931052
(1 row)
```

Here is an example: https://regex101.com/r/xC8fA1/1